# Android Search View with Firebase RecyclerView not showing data

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview, searchview

I can able to retrieve data from Firebase to App through `RecyclerView`. But when I am trying to add Search view its not working.

```
 @Override
 public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

   getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_search, menu);
    final SearchView searchView =(SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(menu.findItem(R.id.menusearch));
    SearchManager searchManager =(SearchManager) getSystemService(SEARCH_SERVICE);        searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName());
    //searchView.setSubmitButtonEnabled(true);

    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
       @Override
       public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
           return false;
       }

       @Override
       public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
          //SearchText.setText(newText);
           Query Q = mDatabase.child("Recipees").orderByChild("cusine").startAt(newText).endAt("");
           FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<ImageRetrieve, BlogViewHolder> firebaseRecyclerAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<ImageRetrieve, BlogViewHolder>(

                   ImageRetrieve.class,
                   R.layout.recipe_row,
                   BlogViewHolder.class,
                   Q

           ) {
               @Override
               protected void populateViewHolder(BlogViewHolder viewHolder, ImageRetrieve model, int position) {

                   viewHolder.setCusine(model.getCusine());
                   viewHolder.setCatagory(model.getCatagory());
                   viewHolder.setRecipe(model.getRecipe());
                   viewHolder.setUrl(getApplicationContext(), model.getUrl());

               }
           };

           mRecipeList.setAdapter(firebaseRecyclerAdapter);



           return false;
       }


   });
   return true;
   }
```

Comment: is firebase query returning some to you?

Comment: regarding Search nothing , i can retrieve same Data in Recycle view

Comment: So that mean query have wrong: Try This: mDatabase.child("Recipees").orderByChild("cusine").equalTo(newText);

Answer (score 1):

Try this it may help :

```
Query Q = mDatabase.child("Recipees").orderByChild("cusine").startAt(newText).endAt(newText+"\uf8ff");
```

Comment: the worst thing about firebase is searching in most case they do it through an other api using elastic search, i guess implementing your own adapter and getting the list then filtering it will be your best choice

Answer (score 0):

So that mean query have wrong.
Try This:-->

```
mDatabase.child("Recipees").orderByChild("cusine").equalTo(n‌​ewText);
```

Comment: Still no luck !!

Answer (score 0):

Try the code below, it might be helpful:

```
     searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String text) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String text) {

            // if searchView is not empty
            if(!text.isEmpty()){
              // call seearch method if user starts typing
                search(text);
            }

            //else
            else{
                // set TextField empty
                search("");
            }

            return true;
        }
    });
```

// method to perform search

```
private void search(String newText)
{

   ArrayList<> searchList = new ArrayList<>();


    // creates a query to initiate the search
   Query Q = mDatabase.child("Recipees")
    .orderByChild("cusine").startAt(newText).endAt(newText + "\uf8ff");


    query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            if(dataSnapshot.hasChildren()){

                //clears the arrayList
                searchList.clear();

                for(DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){

                    final ImageRetrieve imageRetrieve = 
                     snapshot.getValue(ImageRetrieve.class);

                    //adds the rooms searched to the arrayList
                    searchList.add(imageRetrieve);

                }

            //NB: recyclerView is the view object in your activity that populates data

                FirebaseRecyclerAdapter firebaseRecyclerAdapter =
                        new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter(yourActivity.this,searchList);
                recyclerView.setAdapter(firebaseRecyclerAdapter);

                firebaseRecyclerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            // display message if error occurs

        }
    });

}
```